# In the classical/Keplerian orbital elements, how is argument of the periapsis related to right ascension of periapsis - why is (Π = Ω + ω) true?

Tags: orbital-motion

Reading up on orbital mechanics, I met this relationship between orbital elements Π = Ω + ω. To lay out my understanding:

- Π = right ascension of the periapsis, measured in the reference plane: shown by the red dotted line in [diagram 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQg1z.png), which is the orbital arc from the ascending node to the periapsis projected onto the reference plane.
- Ω = right ascension of the ascending node, also measured in the reference plane: shown in [diagram 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSA8U.png) as the black arc from the reference frame's X-axis to the ascending node.
- ω = argument of the periapsis, measured in the *orbital* plane: shown in [diagram 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQg1z.png) as the black arc from the ascending node to the periapsis.

As far as I know, the angle equal to (Π - Ω) would be the projection of ω onto the reference plane, which would [not be equal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4012266/evolution-of-the-projected-angle-with-dihedral-angle) to ω in cases where the orbit is not coplanar with the reference plane.

What part of my understanding is wrong or incomplete?
Thanks